# Cannot switch between threads in Android Studio debugger

Tags: multithreading, android-studio, debugging

**Environment:**
Android Studio Bumblebee | **2021.1.1 Patch 3**
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675, built on March 17, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.ctrip.wireless.android.build (1.0.7), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40)

[image]

When breakpoints are hit on different threads, I should be able to switch between them using the dropdown list under the "Frames" tab. Recently I just found that the dropdown list would not open when I clicked on it. I can still switch to other threads using the "Threads" tab though but that would be much more inconvenient. Is this a new feature in Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was gone after I upgraded AS.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it has been fixed in the following version of AS:

Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 16
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.ctrip.wireless.android.build (1.0.7)